# Cannot get the Likes of a Photo Object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

I am using the Graph API in my iOS app. When I do a request of type [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"] ..
I do get the expected result (the 25 most recent Photo object). I can see in the results the comments, tags... for each photo but cannot see the likes for each photo.
Is this something that anybody else experienced before or am I missing some permissions approval?
Prior retrieving the photos, I do [facebook authorize:] with the following permissions : "user_photos", "friends_photos".
It just seems to me that the likes property is missing from the returned objects...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Getting likes is a separate graph API call. Also I wouldn't count on the comments in the photo call, this seems to be an undocumented feature.

The URL for like is: `https://graph.facebook.com/{photo ID}/likes`
And similarly for comments: `https://graph.facebook.com/{photo ID}/comments`

The [Photo object documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) is your friend here.

You could combine these calls using a [batch request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) to get all of the photo ids then gets the likes and comments for each photo ID.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer. I also tried your suggestion but it comes back with 

{
   "data": [
      
   ]
}

have you managed yourself to get a correct result ?
I still think that this is a bit weird that the GRaph API call returns all the properties as expected per the link you sent BUT not  the likes. (it does though give you the likes for each comment of a given photo...)

Comment: Yes we actually do the batch request I've described above to get photo likes and comments. Batch requests can be difficult to get right. I had to start with a simple request, just getting the photos, then add a subsequent request for the likes, then the comments. I found the Graph API Explorer very helpful in getting the syntax right. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. I should mention that we use our own SDK, I don't know anything about how the iOS SDK handles batch requests. Sorry.

Comment: ok thanks for that. I will keep using the iOS SDK for the graph API calls and see which information I can get from that.
cheers.